# how to import 2-3 notebooks in 1 notebook using Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

working directory:

```
%pwd

Out[1]:
u'C:\\Users\\school\\Documents\\try\\code'


code dir has 2 files: 

my_module.py
my_script.py

Code in my_module.py

def hello_printer():
print("Hello world!")
name = "John"

code in my_script.py
import my_module

my_module.hello_printer()
print("Creator:", my_module.name)
```

The 'my_module.py' is designed as a module whose code can be imported and reused in other Python files. You can see that by its content: it doesn't call for any action, just defines functions and variables. In contrast, the 'my_script.py' is designed as a top-level script which runs the Python program - it explicitly calls a function hello_printer and prints a variable's value to the screen.

if i use normal python and save the above notebooks as normal .py script and if i run the 'my_script.py' file in the terminal i get the below output.

```
$ python my_script.py

Hello world!
Creator: John
```

but i want to implement this concept in Juypter notebooks and not use the basic python ide.

need to understand the complete process. do i need to create both the notebooks. How will be the directory structure.

Comment: does [this](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html) link help?